# Hidden error with cordova build CLI and facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, ant

I added the facebook sdk through `cordova add plugin` and referenced the Facebook SDK in eclipse on the android project.

On Eclipse I have no error on build but when I try to build in command line with `cordova build` the build fails with a hidden error.
http://pastebin.com/Z0jf3a6Z

Is there a way to show more context with cordova build or more low level build I could get with ant on a cordova project ? I just need to know what's the error, even if I could replicate it on eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

After a small break and clearing my mind I found the problem and solution.

First, to add more verbosity to the ant build process in CLI you need to edit the build.xml file located in your `SDK_PATH/tools/ant/build.xml` and look for the property `verbosity` and set it to true.

This helped me realize the error was actually the warnings themselves since the `Werror` flag was used in the Facebook SDK compile phase that was failing. So you need to edit the `ant.properties` of the lib that is failing and remove the `Werror` flag, be careful as some warnings might be important.

Lastly, the build was failing at the `-code-gen` phase with a message about an `invalid resource directory name`, if you have this message you need to close eclipse and run `ant clean` on the lib/project that is failing and building again without launching eclipse.

I hope this helps.